# Очищается ли память от переменных из функций в Python?

Tags: python, память

Только знакомлюсь с управлением памятью в Python, поэтому такой глупый вопрос.

Допустим есть программа которая должна работать в фоне очень долго, часов 6+.
И в эту программу прилетают "задания", которые запускают какие-то функции. Для примера такая бесполезная функция:

```
def foo():
    r = requests.get("https://mylink.com")
    data = json.loads(r.text)
    value = data["arg"]
    if value > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

foo()
```

И такая функция выполняется часто, десятки раз.
Что будет с памятью, остаются ли `r`,`data`,`value` в памяти? Нужно ли их принудительно очищать через `del` или сборщик сам всё очистит и не стоит беспокоиться что память забьётся этими переменными, используемыми исключительно внутри этой функции?

И подобный вопрос на случай если вместо `False` или `True` возвращалось бы что-то из функции, например `value`, и записывалось в переменную `var` для использования бы в другой функции как аргумент. `var` остаётся в памяти? Если его значение перезаписывается, то `var` в памяти такой один и его желательно удалить как только он будет не нужен?

Comment: `del` удалит только ссылку, а само значение останется в памяти до тех пор, пока сборщик не решит прибраться. И скорее всего использовать `del` нет смысла, сборщик сам разберётся. Значения в памяти остаются до тех пор, пока на них остаётся хотя бы одна ссылка; когда ссылок больше нет — за ними придёт сборщик

Comment: Из документации: "в настоящее время CPython использует схему подсчета ссылок с (необязательно) отложенным обнаружением циклически связанного мусора, который собирает большинство объектов, как только они становятся недоступными, но не гарантирует сбор мусора, содержащего циклические ссылки... https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#:~:text=are%20still%20reachable.-,CPython%20implementation%20detail%3A,-CPython%20currently%20uses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не вдаваться в подробности работы самого сборщика мусора, то:

1. Если вы используете какие-то переменные исключительно внутри функции, то они являются локальными и их содержимое не сохраняется после выхода из функции, очищать их не нужно
2. Если вы в основной части кода используете какую-то переменную для разных целей, перезаписывая её содержимое, то предыдущее значение очищать не нужно, как только на объект, который был в переменной ранее, исчезнут ссылки, эта память будет в последствии очищена сборщиком мусора
3. А вот если вы загружаете что-то большое в какие-то переменные на верхнем уровне кода и так эти переменные и продолжают дальше указывать на эти большие объекты, то эти объекты продолжают занимать память. Если эти объекты вам больше не нужны, то можете в явном виде их удалить через `del имя_переменной`. Но в хорошо написанной программе, разбитой на функции, это обычно не требуется. Если программа хорошо отрефакторена и все как-то связанные действия у вас происходят в отдельных функциях, то по выходе из функции эти данные сами почистятся, об этом не нужно заботиться.

Таким образом, если грамотно писать код, разбивать его на классы и небольшие функции, а не делать всё в одной большой простыне кода, то надобности в принудительной чистке памяти через использование `del` возникать вообще не должно.

Обычно `del` может быть нужен когда вы пишете довольно "плоский" код к примеру в `Jupyter Notebook` и у вас все объекты хранятся на одном уровне программы.